# Why people[1].a don't have access to properties from class User?

Tags: javascript, class, prototype, proto

Why people[1].a don't have access to properties from class User, but have need nested from through **proto** ?!

```
class User {
        constructor(name, age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        static a = 12;
    }

    class User2 extends User {}

    let people = [
        new User2('Vasia', 20),
        new User2('Peter', 19),
        new User2('Misha', 21),
    ]



    console.dir(User2.a) // 12
    console.dir(people[1].a) // ?????
```

Comment: Why not `User2.age` but `people[1].age`?

Comment: @Bergi because User2.a don't have any proprietes 'a' it just was extends from User if i call `User.a` she will be return undefined because this.a nested from User do not have any proprietes, Sorry for language skill i just started learn english :D and js

PS: I'm not sure if i response correct and if not hard please give a feedback ^_^

Comment: I just wanted to hint at the difference between the `age` and `a` properties - one exists on instances, the other exists on classes.

Comment: @Bergi thx you absolutely right now i guess understand :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` properties appear on the Class objects. They do not appear on *instances* of the class.

They are intended to hold static methods.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static):

> The static keyword defines a static method for a class. Static methods aren't called on instances of the class. Instead, they're called on the class itself. **These are often utility functions, such as functions to create or clone objects.**